# How to delete the News app on OSX?

Tags: applications, macos

I want to remove the News app from my computer. I tried to remove it myself:

```
dsenableroot
su - root
sudo rm -rf /Applications/News.app
```

*"Operation not permitted"*

It appears I no longer in control of my computer.

Can somebody help me pull this app out of my machine?

Comment: Why don't you just turn off the notifications for News?  I've all notifications for that app turned off for months and I'm never bothered by alerts of any kind, like the one you experiences.

Comment: Failing that you could boot into recovery mode and turn off System Integrity Protection (SIP) with a **csrutil disable.** Reboot and delete the app. I would then boot into recovery mode and turn SIP back on with a **csrutil enable.** But what I would REALLY do and have done is just turn off notifications and ignore it. News is a small app and can be ignored.

Comment: News app is horrible and I want to remove it - that's why. I don't want the propaganda on my hardware thank you very much.

Comment: On a MacBook running Big Sur 11.7.5 the News app is "using significant energy" and runs down the battery when  the Mac is supposed to sleep. This is a _very good reason_ to get rid of it. And yes, I **have disabled** its notifications. I don't use News, I didn't even know it existed until it showed up in the Battery dropdown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NOTE:** At the time this question/answer was posted the then current release of **macOS** was **macOS Mojave**. Things have changed in **macOS Catalina** and later. Especially in **macOS Big Sur** and later, the **Macintosh HD** is a cryptographically signed read-only volume and these directions do not apply to it or later versions of **macOS**. Additional steps and directions requires for **macOS Big Sur** and later, however breaking the cryptographically signed read-only volume breaks **FileVault** and therefore will not be provided.

---

For **macOS Mojave** and earlier.

You **do not** need to disable **System Integrity Protection** (SIP).

To delete the **News** app, do the following:

1. Backup **News.app** with via **Time Machine** or making a **Zip** archive.

- For the **Zip** archive, *right-click* it and select: **Compress "News"**

1. Shutdown your Mac.
2. Boot to **Recovery Mode**. Press **⌘R** when starting your Mac.
3. Open **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu.
4. Run the following *compound command* adjusting **Macintosh HD** as necessary if you've modified the *default name* of the *primary startup volume*:

   ```
    rm -r "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications/News.app"; reboot
   ```
5. After rebooting from **Recovery Mode**, if you still have the **News** icon on the **Dock**, *right-click* it and select: **Options** > **Remove from Dock**

---

Note that while this does remove the **News.app**, it may/will reappear when **macOS** is updated/upgraded and will need to be deleted again.

If after having done this and you want to restore the **News** app, then restore it using **Time Machine**, if you backed it up in that manner, or if you created the **Zip** archive, it would have been created in the **/Applications** folder, if you moved it elsewhere, move it back and then do the following:

1. Shutdown your Mac.
2. Boot to **Recovery Mode**. Press **⌘R** when starting your Mac.
3. Open **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu.
4. Run the following *compound command* adjusting **Macintosh HD** as necessary if you've modified the *default name* of the *primary startup volume*:

   ```
    cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications"; ../usr/bin/unzip News.zip; reboot
   ```

Comment: While the method posted above could be considered more secure, I recommend fully turning off SIP so you don't have to boot into Recovery Mode again after OS updates. You're still protected by the normal root permission system used by every Linux OS and macOS up through 10.10.

Comment: I do not recommend turning off SIP indefinitely!

Comment: One caveat to note: this is permanent. If you change your mind and decide you want the News app back, you will likely need to do a full reinstall. macOS updates will sometimes restore the app, but it will be a broken version you can't actually open (so you'll need to just delete it again.) If you're okay with that, I never experience ill effects from removing default apps, and have been doing it for the past decade...

Comment: @Wowfunhappy, Assuming one has backed it up, either via Time Machine or creating a Zip archive, it can easily be restored without the need to reinstall the whole OS. Additionally, without a backup it can still be restored without having to reinstall the whole OS, although the steps necessary are much easier with having a backup then having to extract the app from the installer.

Comment: Yeah, there's also Pacifist. I've just run into weird issues with doing that in the past. I suspect there's some permissions or attributes in play that don't always get restored.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy, This is why one should use Time Machine or have a Zip archive, however there is a way to use Pacifist however is not a straight forward process. FWIW I do not post what I haven't already done and tested and know for a fact that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Brief addendum to @user3439894's answer:

- You might have to mount the volume first (after entering in recovery mode but before opening the terminal).
- The news app may be located at `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/Applications/News.app`–note `/System/`–(Catalina 10.15.2).