# How can I uninstall or disable the News app on macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, news.app, apple-news

I never use it, and according to [CleanMyMac](https://cleanmymac.macpaw.com/) it's using > 6GB for its cache

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete the News app on OSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359488/how-to-delete-the-news-app-on-osx)

Comment: If you haven't set it up, then it shouldn't use any cache. So I'd question whether CleanMyMac is correct. (I don't recommend using it at all.) Generally, you can't delete system apps.

Comment: On Big Sur and beyond, you cannot delete system apps (without knowing very well what you are doing; if you have to ask about it, you probably shouldn't attempt it).

Comment: @benwiggy I wonder if the cache is coming from the Stocks app, which has a news component to it. I do use that app regularly.